# Optimal size for an image in a bootstrap carousel for mobile and web

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

First time trying to use a carousel in  my web page and am having trouble placing an image in each slide of the carousel.

```
<div class="carouselContainer">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Carousel indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>   
           <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="active item one">
                   <img src="slide1.png"/>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h3>Slide 1</h3>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item two">
                   <img src="slide2.png"/>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h3>Slide 2</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item three">
                   <img src="slide3.png"/>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h3>Slide 3</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Carousel controls -->
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The carousel shows up fine and can navigate just fine between slides, but my images I put in them:

- Perfect when I resize the browser window to a smaller size (mobile size)
- Extremely blurry, too large, and slightly distorted on a fully  sized window.

Is there an optimal size for images for carousels or am I missing something about a option to help scale images with the size of the window?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The quality of your images at different sizes is going to depend on the dimensions of the images themselves. A 320 pixel wide image is going to look very pixelated if your carousel stretches it to fit any modern desktop resolution (usually higher than 1024 these days.)

My suggestion would be to look at what the dimensions of your image files are, and if they are indeed only suitable for mobile (i.e. they're only ~320px wide), you may need to look into getting higher-resolution images, if possible. A lot of this will depend on the source of your images, obviously (are they your files, so you can export higher resolution versions? Or are they images you got from the internet, in which case does the source website offer larger versions?)

Edit:
Regarding the optimal size for carousels, there really is no such thing these days, as devices come in all shapes and sizes. Your best bet is to look into providing different sized images for different device sizes and resolutions. There are multiple ways to accomplish this, but you'll find some good information here: http://responsiveimages.org/, and you can find many tutorials about this technique across the web.

Here's an example of what this looks like with some HTML and sample images:

```css
.wide {
    width: 1280px;
}

.wide img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wide">
    This image will look pixelated:
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/100">
</div>
    
<div class="wide">
    This image will not look pixelated:
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1280/400">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimal image resolution depends on your website design, specially width of your slider. If you are designing a default fixed width website then your image width should be 1200px width (default bootstrap template width is 1200px without padding 1170px).

but if you want a full width slider (fit according to the browser width) then I suggest you to find a high quality image of 1920px width. because according to statcounter.com almost 12.7% monitor have 1920px width. And obviously the most popular resolution is 1367px (43.6%). so if you didn't find a image of width 1920px at least try to use a 1367px image.

You can use two image for two different resolution also. all you need is the srcset attribute on the HTML img tag.

```html
<img src="small.jpg" srcset="medium.jpg 1367w, large.jpg 1920w">
```

you can read more about it in: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/